# Issue while parsing the output in batch file

Tags: parsing, batch-file

Can anyone please suggest me how can I get the value of **9** from the below output.

```
"Version

"9.0.56336
```

I know that we need to parse the output and get that value. But, am not succeded to get that.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. What have you tried? Did something almost work? What error message do you get? Is the text in a file or is it the output of a program?

Comment: This is the command I used to get the version and its value. FOR /F "tokens=* delims= " %%a IN ('"wmic product where "Name like 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable'" get version"') do echo "%%%a"

Comment: Here Am unable to assign the output to a variable, this is the command I used to set the output.  for /f "tokens=3 delims=." %%a in ('wmic product where "Name like 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable'" get Version') do set fine="%%%a"
echo fine:%fine%

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "fine="9.0.56336"
ECHO %fine%
SET "fine=%fine:"=%"
ECHO %fine%
FOR /f "delims=." %%a IN ("%fine%") DO SET "fine=%%a"
ECHO %fine%

GOTO :EOF
```

Your `...set fine="%%%a" echo fine:%fine%`

should be on two separate lines

```
...set fine="%%a"
echo fine:%fine%
```

**and** there should be two, not three `%`s

This does set `fine` to the last line (I believe - haven't got the same installation, so I can't test it)

If you indeed have `"9.0.56336` as your data content, then the above processing should get the `9`.

Comment: Hi Magoo, your code is working fine , but here my trouble is after executing the below line version is not set to the fine variable.  for /f "tokens=3 delims=." %%a in ('wmic product where "Name like 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable'" get Version') do set fine="%%a"

Comment: Its setting some junk value "56336  ".

Comment: use `tokens=1` and it should get the 9

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. Try editing-in the exact response you are seeing ...do set fine="%%a" [new line] ECHO fine:%fine%     BTW - `set fine="%%a"` and `set "fine=%%a` are vastly different. If `%%a` contains the string `something` then the first will set `fine` to the value `"something"` whereas the second will set `fine` to `something` - the first is quoted, the second, not.